# get rid of the ETA and rate on tqdm progress bar?

Tags: python, tqdm

There is a way to get rid of the ETA and rate of a tqdm progress bar?

I've this bar:

```
fuoco: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 10/10 [00:05<00:00,  2.00it/s]
```

I need to remove the elapsed and remaining time:

```
10/10 [00:05<00:00,  2.00it/s]
```

Comment: Customize the [`bar_format` parameter](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm#parameters).

Answer (score 4):

You need to provide `bar_format` [parameter](https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/#parameters) if you want to have other information/format than default, please try following

```
bar_format='{elapsed}<{remaining}'
```

example

```
import time
import tqdm
for i in tqdm.tqdm(range(100),bar_format='{elapsed}<{remaining}'):
    time.sleep(1)
```

look after finish

```
01:41<00:00
```

Consult linked page too see other possible values to use in `bar_format`.

Comment: I think the person that asked the question wanted to keep  only the progress bar and remove the elapsed and remaining time

Comment: exactly i need to remove this two parameter, can you help me, i can't find the way

Comment: @gabrieletosti plese try `bar_format='{bar}'` and write if it does what you want

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the iterable into an object without a length.
For example:

```
import time
import tqdm
for i in tqdm.tqdm(iter(range(100)),bar_format='{elapsed}<{remaining}'):
    ##             ^^^^
    ## iter returns an iterator without a known length
    ## when the length is unknown tqdm won't print ETA info 
    time.sleep(1)
```